# MySQL - How to order a joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    Artist.name
    Product.id
FROM
    Artist
INNER JOIN
    Product
ON
    Product.artist_id = Artist.id
GROUP BY
    Artist.artist_id
ORDER BY
    Artist.last_name, Artist.first_name;
```

I need the `Product.id` that is returned to be the latest record i.e. the highest `id` for each artist. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY Product.artist_id DESC LIMIT 1?

Comment: What I want returned is a list of artist's names with their latest product...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT
    Artist.name,
    max(Product.id)
FROM
    Artist
INNER JOIN
    Product
ON
    Product.artist_id = Artist.id
GROUP BY
    Artist.artist_id, Artist.name
ORDER BY
    Artist.last_name, Artist.first_name;
```

or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
Artist.name
MAX(Product.id) as highest_id
```

this might work

using ID to indicate `latest` is far from ideal,
you should consider to add a date-time column (such as launch_date),

with this date tracking field,
you can do the sorting correctly